# Converting a DateTime Index value to an Index Number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, dataframe

If I have a dataframe that has a datetime index and I get the first valid index by using series.first_valid_index - It returns a the date time of the first non nan which is what I'm looking for however:

Is there a way to get the index number that the datetime value corresponds to. For example, it returns 2018-07-16 but I'd like to know that's the 18th row of the dataframe?

If not, is there a way to count the rows from the beginning of the dataframe to that index value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***TLDR***: If you're asking for a way to map a given index value (in this case a `DatetimeIndex`) to its integer equivalent, you are asking for `get_loc`, if you just want to find the integer index from the Series, use `argmax` with the underlying `numpy` array.

***Setup***

```
np.random.seed(3483203)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([0, np.nan], 5),
    index=pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', freq='1D', periods=5)
)
```

```
              0
2018-01-01  NaN
2018-01-02  NaN
2018-01-03  0.0
2018-01-04  NaN
2018-01-05  NaN
```

---

Use [`pandas.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) here, which is a general function to return an integer index for a given label:

```
>>> idx = df[0].first_valid_index()
>>> idx
Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00', freq='D')
>>> df.index.get_loc(idx)
2
```

If you want to avoid finding the `datetime` index at all, you may use `argmax` on the underlying `numpy` array:

```
>>> np.argmax(~np.isnan(df[0].values))
2
```

Comment: yea i was attempting to use get_loc but my syntax was off. this nailed it. thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! Like I noted above, `get_loc` is the correct way to find the integer index, given a Datetime index.  However, if you want to skip that intermediate step, use the `argmax` solution at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would try following (untested):

```
x = len(df)
num_index = range(0,x,1)
df =  df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index(num_index)
```

Comment: And if you still want to have the inital index (with datetime) use `df['date'] = df.index` before resetting your index.

Comment: Remove old index column `df = df.drop('index', axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.arwhere` along with `np.isnan` or with `pd.notnull`:

```
np.argwhere(~np.isnan(s)).flat[0]
# or:
# np.argwhere(pd.notnull(s)).flat[0]
```

Given the Series:

```
>>> s
2018-09-27    NaN
2018-09-28    NaN
2018-09-29    5.0
2018-09-30    5.0
2018-10-01    NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

You get:

```
>>> np.argwhere(~np.isnan(s)).flat[0]
2
```

Alternatively, just reset the index and get `first_valid_index`:

```
>>> s.reset_index()[0].first_valid_index()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary, with key being the datetime object & its value being your index.
Sample code for your reference:

```
timestamp=df.iloc[0:,0].tolist()
timestamp_dict={}
number=0
for time in timestamp:
    timestamp_dict[time]=number
    number+=1
```

Hope it helps out.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to convert the "x" into dataFrame and than set the inplace to true.

```
x = len(df)
df["num_index"] = range(0, x, 1)
df.set_index(df['num_index'], inplace=True)
```

**Note:** But this code will completely replace the date index to num_index.

**Solution 2:**
If you want to keep the date index and replace the index with num_index than you should apply following code:

```
df['Date'] = df.index
x = len(df)
df["num_index"] = range(0, x, 1)
df.set_index(df['num_index'], inplace=True)
```

Now, you have the Date and the number as the index.

**Solution 3:**
the simplest way is to reset the index

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

this will create an index starting from 0 and a column with the same name the index.